# Dual monitor setup - filickering issue with ATI Radeon open source driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, radeon, external-monitor, flicker

I'm having a flickering issue on a Toshiba Satellite A305 laptop with Radeon Mobility HD3450 graphic card and external monitor setup.

Ubuntu 14.04 with NO proprietary ATI drivers installed.
The dual display setup works without issues when both monitors (built-in and external) are on.

The flickering issue is triggered only when I close the laptop lid and only the external display is on. It is noticeable when I move the mouse or type something on the keyboard.

Here you can see an YouTube video - [Ubuntu 14.04 + ATI Radeon screen flickering on external display](http://youtu.be/_gJJMEpYw7s).

Usually I use the system mostly with the external display only which is impossible now because of the flickering issue. I would like to keep dual display mode working with no problems as it is right now, but also to fix the issue when only the external display is on.

Does anybody know a solution for this issue?

Here is some additional information:

uname -r

```
3.13.0-46-generic
```

Xorg -version

```
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux Trusty-A305 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic root=UUID=c6f36fad-064f-46a1-9580-2c12ef45db02 ro persistent quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
```

ldd --version

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
```

sudo lshw -c video

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d6300000-d630ffff memory:d6320000-d633ffff
```

lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'

```
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'

```
[   14.653989] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   14.699676] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   14.699767] fb: conflicting fb hw usage radeondrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
[   14.704104] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV620 0x1002:0x95C4 0x1179:0xFF1C).
[   14.704374] [drm] register mmio base: 0xD6300000
[   14.704376] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[   14.704538] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 256M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000000FFFFFFF (256M used)
[   14.704541] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000002FFFFFFF
[   14.704543] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=256M, BAR=256M
[   14.704545] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[   14.706482] [drm] radeon: 256M of VRAM memory ready
[   14.706484] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[   14.706500] [drm] Loading RV620 Microcode
[   14.912697] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[   14.944276] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   14.944335] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   14.944339] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800b37e7c00
[   14.944342] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800b37e7c0c
[   14.944345] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   14.944346] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   14.944348] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   14.944377] radeon 0000:01:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.944394] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   14.944426] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   14.981917] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   14.981927] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   14.982343] [drm] Enabling audio 0 support
[   14.982364] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   14.982379] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   14.982785] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   14.982787] [drm] Connector 0:
[   14.982789] [drm]   LVDS-1
[   14.982791] [drm]   DDC: 0x7f68 0x7f68 0x7f6c 0x7f6c 0x7f70 0x7f70 0x7f74 0x7f74
[   14.982792] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.982794] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_LVTMA
[   14.982796] [drm] Connector 1:
[   14.982797] [drm]   VGA-1
[   14.982799] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[   14.982800] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.982802] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   14.982803] [drm] Connector 2:
[   14.982805] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[   14.982806] [drm]   HPD1
[   14.982808] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[   14.982809] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.982811] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   14.982812] [drm] Connector 3:
[   14.982813] [drm]   DIN-1
[   14.982815] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.982816] [drm]     TV1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC2
[   14.982875] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[   16.036604] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0141000
[   16.036608] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[   16.036610] [drm] size 8294400
[   16.036611] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   16.036612] [drm]    pitch is 7680
[   16.036804] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   16.108015] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   16.108017] radeon 0000:01:00.0: registered panic notifier
[   16.108088] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.36.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

After running the following command (from [Radeon Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver))

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
```

for OpenGL renderer string I've got:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe it's a [long-standing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/318325) and I haven't found a fix or workaround EXCEPT to never close the lid or put the laptop to sleep. I figure there probably is a way to fix it, but the Radeon folks are not available or motivated to fix a bug affecting a long-discontinued chip.

About the only things you can do to get it fixed is verify it's the same bug (it sounds like it to me, but you'll want to be sure) click the "this affects me too" button in launchpad, and maybe look to see if it's getting any attention with the radeon folks "upstream" of Ubuntu.

Oh and of course if you are familiar with coding graphics drivers maybe you're the one who can fix it!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. So the only way to go around this is to install the proprietary driver fglrx?

Comment: Actually it is not setup to sleep when lid is closed. Just switching to the external display.

Comment: Last time I looked the proprietary driver specifically excluded all the older chips. :-(

Comment: I have never tried triggering it with an external display, so it is possible you are seeing a different bug but I strongly suspect it is the same one.

Comment: Perhaps older version of the fglrx will work, I'll try and see. Wanted to use the open source driver which is by default and not wasting time installing the proprietary.

Comment: Be sure to let me know if you find a workaround... Also try suspending to verify the behavior in case it is a different bug.

Comment: What should I try, suspend and resume to see if the issue persists? I've had an older version of fglrx installed on Ubuntu 12.04 on the same machine and it was working flawlessly. Then I've switched to 14.04 and I'm still on the open source driver using it with dual screens both active, otherwise when the lid is closed this flickering issue is triggered on the external screen.

Comment: You may be seeing a completely different issue because I am nearly certain the "flicker on suspend" bug long precedes Ubuntu 12.04. You may be having a similar bug affect a card but your exact bug may differ.